# java 8 compare 2 lists based on property

Tags: java, list, java-8, compare, java-stream

I have to compare elements on two list (list1 to list2) and when the elements match with that of the code property,
I have to replace with the value of tobereplace property.

In list1 I have

```
[{code:"1", name:"first name", tobereplace: ""} , {code:"2", name:"first name1", tobereplace: ""}, 
{code:"3", name:"first name2", tobereplace: ""}, {code:"4", name:"first name3", tobereplace: ""}]
```

in List2 I have:

```
[{code:"1", name:"first name", tobereplace: ""} , {code:"2", name:"first name1", tobereplace: "" }, 
{code:"3", name:"first name2", tobereplace: ""}, {code:"4", name:"first name3", tobereplace: "this should come in list1"}]
```

Ideally,List1 should have values of List2;
How can we achieve this using Java8 streams

Comment: You base in all properties or just a specific one?

Comment: specific one property

Comment: Which one `tobereplace` ?

Comment: yes, tobereplace property

Comment: can you show us the expected result please?

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that the class is named `Foo` and that the field to change is `String valueToReplace`  with getter/setter, you could use `listOne.replaceAll()` in this way :

```
list1.replaceAll(one ->  list2.stream()
                              .filter(other -> other.getCode().equals(one.getCode())
                              .findAny()
                              .map(Foo::getValueToReplace)
                              .ifPresent( newValue -> one.setValueToReplace(newValue));
                        return one;
                )
```

The idea is for each elements of `list1` you replace the `valueToReplace` field of it by the value of the first match of `list2`. Otherwise you do nothing.
This code is not as efficient as it could but for small lists it is perfect.
For bigger lists, using a `Map` to store `code/valueToReplace` is very welcome.

```
// supposing that the code are unique in each list
Map<Integer, String>  mapOfValueToReplaceByCode =
    list2.stream()
         .collect(toMap(Foo::getCode, Foo::getValueToReplace));

list1.replaceAll(one -> {
                 String newValue = mapOfValueToReplaceByCode.get(one.getCode());
                 if (newValue != null){ 
                     one.setValueToReplace(newValue);
                 }
                  return one;
                )
```

Comment: if `list2` contains duplicated keys you will get `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key %s (attempted merging values %s and %s)`

Comment: Agreed. That's why I added this comment before this operation : "supposing that the code are unique in each list". Handling the duplicates would make core more complex as required and according to the requirement if the code is not unique inside the list, I think that there is a misconception somewhere : why replace with the first element found and not the second found ?

Comment: to me the requirement is explain all cases, including no pre-aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Just keep the replace values in a map (with code as key) and then iterate over list1 to modify where necessary.

```
Map<String, String> replaceValues = list2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.code, x -> x.tobereplace));
list1.stream
    .filter(x -> replaceValues.containsKey(x.code))
    .forEach(x -> x.tobereplace = replaceValues.get(x.code));
```

**EDIT**

As josejuan points out in the comments, the `Collectors.toMap` will throw an exception if list2 contains duplicate values. The OP doesn't really specify what to do in that case, but the solution is using a merge function in the `Collectors.toMap`.

This will use the first element it encounters with any given code:

```
Map<String, String> replaceValues = list2.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.code, x -> x.tobereplace, (x1, x2) -> x1));
```

The merge policy could be anything, like using the first element with a non-empty value e.g.

If the list was known to not have duplicates, please use a Set instead of a List. It will make things clearer for anyone reading the code, and help you avoid unnecessary checks.

Comment: Better use getter and setter instead oft public variables. Beside that the best solution for now.

Comment: I agree, I was just avoiding the verbosity to make the point clearer.

Comment: To be honest, I still use getters and setters in 99% of my code, even if just because it's a convention. But so many times the getters and setters have no logic in them, that I wonder if it's really worth it in those cases. I'm talking mostly about data container "struct-like" classes with no behavior at all.

Comment: if `list2` contains duplicated keys you will get `ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key %s (attempted merging values %s and %s)`

Comment: @josejuan, I just edited the question to show how to add a merge function.